# af:inputfile drag and drop not supported in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, dropzone.js, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

For one of our clients we are building a web application with oracle adf.
One of the requested features of this application is having a drag-and-drop file upload.

Fortunately the af:inputfile component supports this feature out of the box.
Unfortunately that feature is not supported in Internet Explorer 11, which we absolutely have to support.

Now I have been trying to get it to work using the dropzone.js library and the drag and drop functionality seems to be working. but I haven't been able to get the POST request to the ADF side of things quite right.

Even if I did it would be a lot of custom code that would have to be maintained, if it's the only way to make it work that is fine but if there is a more elegant solution to this I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use ADF JavaScript APIs, more specifically `AdfFileUploadManager`(https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/api-reference-javascript-faces/oracle/adf/view/js/util/AdfFileUploadManager.html)

You need to instantiate it by giving it the ADF Component reference, which that can be an af:inputFile with display="none"

Then you can utilise your DropZone or any other functionality and use addFileToQueue to send this information to server side and convert it to UploadedFile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have managed to get the files to the Java part of things now, but even though it seems the files are being transferred correctly. My WebLogic server is spamming me with errors. More specifically: No window specified in request and popView() No view has been pushed. Any thoughts on this?